# What is the design process (principles or guidlines) for Unity's UX and GUI?

Tags: unity, gui, process, brainstorm

I recently started to think and develop a new concept of UX and GUI for Ubuntu (desktop, television, mobile and tablet) and I try to start the project on a methodological basis respecting the basic principles of ubuntu.

I've seen many web pages (Ubuntu web site or other sites) and many videos (UDS and others), but I havn't found anywhere an comprehensive guidelines for the creation of other UX (and GUI) or even an explanation of the choices made in Unity. By "Choice" I mean why or how UX (and GUI) are designed: is that based on principles and/or user testing?

To be more clear here is an example from the other: why is Unity app launcher on the left side and not at the top or right? where do I find the answers to such questions?

Tanks

Comment: "where do I find the answers to such questions?" Use appropriate terms in a search engine. You could even search this site itself from the search bar on the top right.

Comment: All of what you're asking is either in this site, or in the Ubuntu site, Unity site and so, moreover you just don't do a UX out of nothing, you first have to learn what that is and all the terms related to it.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my English. I agree with u. But my question was not really about "How to do it?" (even if all infomations and sources that you can share with me will be welcome). My question is more about: **which principles, needs and goals lead the unity UX and GUI?** Moreover, how the Unity UX and GUI pass through the **user experience evaluation**?

Comment: Now, about the location of the information, I didn't find yet how to get all those information explaining why Unity UX and GUI mad some choices in same place, some peep talk on this website (ask) some post related to Mark or Exeperience team, and it's take to long time to find. Maybe, if Canonical lead all UX Choice those kinds of information aren't share freely. So who is the "Chief Experience Officer" for Unity and Ubuntu in Canonical? Maybe I can try to ask him directly and maybe i can get global answers for Unity experience goals.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at unity design blog.
Here for example you find the task switching UX specification:

http://design.canonical.com/the-toolkit/unity-task-switching/

But you are too late, this documents on google docs used to be accessible for everyone, now as the development process of new concepts is restricted to employees and chosen community members you cannot access those docs anymore.